# Why does adiabatic contraction bring Carnot engine back to initial state? (and other questions)

Tags: ideal-gas, adiabatic, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I have many questions (all in bold) around the Carnot cycle. I know I'm not the first one to ask a bunch of questions in the middle of a description of my own understanding, but having read other answers, I really think this is a rather individual process.

I'm using the pebble model : pebbles are resting on a piston which moves vertically under the varying pressure of an ideal gas.

At point A, the gas is at the same temperature as the hot reservoir and its pressure equals $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$.

- Isothermic expansion : remove a pebble. $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ decreases. Gas pressure is now greater
  than $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$, therefore the gas expands until
  pressures are equal. Gas has worked and therefore cooled. Hot
  reservoir transfers heat to the gas. Gas will heat, therefore
  pressure will once again exceed $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ and the piston
  will move up a little more, and so on. **Until I wrote this, my understanding was that one needed to remove pebbles one by one, and I've just realised my description only involves removing one (infinitesimally heavy) pebble, and gas expands until I cease heat exchange. Is there a mistake ?**

At point B, heat exchange ceases. Gas is at hot reservoir temperature, with pressure slightly greater than $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$, therefore expanding an extra (infinitesimal) step.

- Adiabatic expansion : I remove more pebbles (**can I remove them in bulk here ?**), $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ decreases therefore the gas expands
  frictionlessly and cools a good deal. **I'm assuming the gas needs to cool to a temperature close to the cool reservoir's temperature in order to initiate reversible contraction. If so, how do I know this will actually happen ?**

At point C, gas is at the same temperature as cool reservoir.

- Isothermic contraction : I add a pebble. **Does it have to be the same weight as the one I removed to initiate isothermic expansion ?** $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ increases and gas pressure is now less than $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$, therefore gas contracts and receives work from pebbles+atm. It heats a little, gives away this heat to cool reservoir, pressure decreases, gas contracts, and so on.

At point D, heat exchange ceasses. Gas contracts infinitesimally after the last release of heat.

- Adiabatic contraction : I add more pebbles (**as many as I removed to initiate adiabatic expansion ?**). $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ increases again, gas contracts until pressure increases to match $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$.

If all removed pebbles were eventually repositioned on the piston, then $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ obviously has identical initial and final values, and so does gas pressure. Further, having proven that $U=\frac{3}{2}nRT$, one can prove that the volume ratios during adiabatic transitions satisfy $(\frac{T_{cool}}{T_{hot}})^\frac{3}{2}=\frac{V_B}{V_C}=\frac{V_{final}}{V_D}$, therefore, if I want $V_{final}=V_{initial}$, I need to ensure that $V_D=\frac{V_CV_{initial}}{V_B}$. In other words, I can't initiate adiabatic contraction at any random moment, but I need do it when isothermic contraction reaches that precise volume. **Is this correct ? I've never seen this precaution mentioned.**

Comment: I've drafted an answer, but I don't understand your very last question. The adiabatic compression is carried out until all system properties are returned to their initial state, including volume. But I don't understand what you mean by  "$V_{initial}$ isn't the outcome of an adiabatic transition"?

Comment: I'm thinking about how to reformulate it. But as a reply to your comment, I guess I would say : How do we know that it is possible to return all the parameters to their initial state, how do I know that when pressure has returned, volume will also be identical ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does adiabatic contraction bring Carnot engine back to initial
> state?

The short answer is the work done on the gas during the adiabatic compression has to increase the internal energy of the gas by the same amount that the adiabatic expansion reduced the internal energy of the gas, so that the total change in internal energy of the cycle is zero.  Keep in mind there is no change in internal energy of the ideal gas during the isothermal expansion and compression processes.

> …and other questions.
>
> Until I wrote this, my understanding was that one needed to remove
> pebbles one by one, and I've just realised my description only
> involves removing one (infinitesimally heavy) pebble, and gas expands
> until I cease heat exchange. Is there a mistake ?

First, I will assume we are talking about an ideal gas being used in the cycle.

The idea is to carry out the process infinitely slowly so that the gas and the surroundings are always in equilibrium (thermal and mechanical). So you remove one infinitesimally small pebble (I like to use the analogy of a grain of sand) so that the pressure differential is infinitely small, the increase in volume is infinitesimally small, and an infinitesimal amount of heat is transferred across and infinitesimally small temperature difference. Before removing the pebble, you wait until equilibrium is reached.

> At point B, heat exchange ceases. Gas is at hot reservoir temperature,
> with pressure slightly greater than $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$, therefore
> expanding an extra (infinitesimal) step.

At Point B (the start of the reversible adiabatic expansion) the gas pressure is in equilibrium with the surroundings, not greater than. The point is, at avery point in the process the gas is in equilibrium with the surroundings. In terms of elapsed time, think about the time it takes to reestablish equilibrium after removing the pebble as being very brief compared to the time the gas is in equilibrium before removing the next pebble.

> - Adiabatic expansion : I remove more pebbles (**can I remove them in bulk here ?**), $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ decreases therefore the gas
>   expands

No, you can remove them in bulk. You must continue the process of one pebble at a time achieving equilibrium. You need to continue to maintain pressure equilibrium.

> I'm assuming the gas needs to cool to a temperature close to the cool
> reservoir's temperature in order to initiate reversible contraction.
> If so, how do I know this will actually happen ?

Yes. The gas has to gradually cool during the infinitely slow expansion process.   How do you know when it reaches the desired temperature to begin the isothermal compression? How about just monitoring the temperature?

> Isothermic contraction : I add a pebble. Does it have to be the same
> weight as the one I removed to initiate isothermic expansion ?

You are taking the pebble analogy too far. It is an idealization for achieving a reversible process. We are assuming whatever is being remove (pebble, grain of sand, etc.) are all the same mass and that the mass is infinitesimally small.

> $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ increases and gas pressure is now less than
> $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$, therefore gas contracts and receives work from
> pebbles+atm. It heats a little, gives away this heat to cool
> reservoir, pressure decreases, gas contracts, and so on.

Basically, yes. But keep in mind for both the isothermal and adiabatic processes, they are carried out as a series of equilibrium states. They take place infinitely slowly so that the gas and surroundings are always in equilibrium with the surroundings.

> - Adiabatic contraction : I add more pebbles (**as many as I removed to initiate adiabatic expansion ?**). $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$ increases
>   again, gas contracts until pressure increases to match
>   $P_\text{pebbles+atm}$.

Basically, yes. As I said in the beginning, the work done on the gas during the adiabatic compression has to exactly equal and cancel the work done by the gas during the adiabatic expansion, in order that the internal energy of the gas returns to its original state. (There is no change in internal energy during the isothermal expansion and compression processes).

> **but how do I know that this $V_{final}$ is actually the same as $V_{initial}$ (in order for $V_A$ to be well-defined), since
> $V_{initial}$ isn't the outcome of an adiabatic transition ?**

I don't understand what you mean by "$_{}$ isn't the outcome of an adiabatic transition"?

> I'm thinking about how to reformulate it. But as a reply to your
> comment, I guess I would say : How do we know that it is possible to
> return all the parameters to their initial state, how do I know that
> when pressure has returned, volume will also be identical ?

Per the ideal gas equation:

$$PV=nRT$$

Also, for an ideal gas, any process

$$\Delta U=nC_{V}\Delta T$$

For a closed system (no mass transfer) $n$ is a constant. You only need to know any two independent gas properties to determine the rest.  If you know the initial and final pressures are the same, and the initial and final temperatures are the same, from the ideal gas equation the initial and final volumes must also be the same.

> But, of  and , how do I know that even one of them returns to its
> initial value at the same time  does? How do I know that adiabatic
> expansion doesn't reach initial pressure at a different volume (or
> equivalently a different temperature) than initial volume (or
> temperature) ?

It can't reach a different volume if you know the pressure, because for a reversible adiabatic process the pressure and volume are uniquely related. The equation for a reversible adiabatic process is

$$PV^{γ}=Constant$$

or

$$P_{1}V_{1}^{γ}=P_{2}V_{2}^{γ}$$

Where

$$γ=\frac{C_P}{C_V}$$

So if you know the initial pressure and volume, and the specific heats for the gas, and you know either the final pressure or final volume, you know the other.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "How about just monitoring the temperature?" - That would tell me it has happened, if it happens at all. But how do I know that adiabatic expansion will go far enough that the gas will reach the cool reservoir's temperature ?
" If you know the initial and final pressures are the same, and the initial and final temperatures are the same" - How do I know that, under adiabatic contraction, return to initial values of temperature and pressure occur at the same time ? (I notice this is exactly the same issue as with pressure and volume, how do I know that any two parameters return simultaneously?)

Comment: @JamesWell If you return to the initial temperature and pressure, then then you have to return to the initial volume per the ideal gas equation. If you return to the initial temperature and volume, you have to return to the initial pressure. If you return to the initial pressure and volume, you have to return to the initial temperature. Pick any two properties to measure/monitor.

Comment: Of the variables $P$, $T$ and $V$, I see how two of them returning to their initial values ensures the third one does. But, of $T$ and $V$, how do I know that even one of them returns to its initial value at the same time $P$ does? How do I know that adiabatic expansion doesn't reach initial pressure at a different volume (or equivalently a different temperature) than initial volume (or temperature) ? Otherwise formulated, if I choose to enter isothermic expansion when temperature reaches $T_{hot}$, how do I know that at that moment, one of $P$ or $V$ has returned to its initial value?

Comment: After posting my last comment I edited the last part of my question. I'm under the impression that point D where isothermic contraction ends must be placed so as to satisfy precise conditions, in order for adiabatic contraction to bring the cycle to a closed loop. I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: @JamesWell You are way overcomplicating this. For a reversible adiabatic process the pressure and volume are specifically related. I am updating my answer. But I have to say, I do not have any more time to devote to this. So if my update doesn't help you, so be it, and lets move on

Comment: I see why $P_DV_D=P_{final}V_{final}$, but points A and D are separated by two non-adiabatic stages, therefore nothing justifies in my view that $P_DV_D=P_{initial}V_{initial}$. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry James but I’m done. Good luck!